# Curvature of Exponential Family

Tags: statistics

For the $s$-dimensional family $p_{\theta}(x) = \exp[\sum_{i=1}^s \eta_i(\theta)T_i(x) - B(\theta)]h(x)$ with covariance matrix $\Sigma_{\theta}$, if $\theta$ is a scalar, define the *statistical curvature* to be $\gamma_{\theta} = (|M_\theta|/m_{11}^3)^{1/2}$ where $$M_\theta = \begin{pmatrix} m_{11}  &  m_{12}\\  m_{21}  &  m_{22} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\dot{\eta}'_{\theta}\dot{\Sigma}_{\theta}\eta_{\theta}     &     \dot{\eta}'_{\theta}\Sigma_{\theta}\ddot{\eta}_{\theta}\\
\ddot{\eta}'_{\theta}\Sigma_{\theta}\dot{\eta}_{\theta}    &     \ddot{\eta}'_{\theta}\Sigma_{\theta}\ddot{\eta}_{\theta}
\end{pmatrix},$$ with $\eta(\theta) = \{\eta_i(\theta)\})$, $\dot{\eta}(\theta) = \{\eta'_i(\theta)\})$ and $\ddot{\eta}(\theta) = \{\eta''_i(\theta)\})$. Calculate the curvature of the family $C\mathrm{exp}[-\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \theta)^m]$ for $m=2,3,4$. Are the values of $\gamma_{\theta}$ ordered in the way you expected them to be?

This is problem 5.4 in Chapter 1 in Lehmann & Casella Theory of Point Estimation, 2nd Edition. I am confused about how to calculate the curvature of the three cases. Also for $m=3$, $p_{\theta}(x)$ is not an valid density function on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: Using mathmode to simulate italics is not a good idea, as it messes up the spacings between characters.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the editing!